# effectively using jquery and javascript to keep the code separate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building app with php and jquery and it has many ajax loads and functionalities. What i would like to know is what is the most widely used and acceptable way of accessing dom elements with jquery and adding events to it using jquery and javascript and if there is any rule of thumb to follow for the following instances.(and how i do them now)

A query generates a list of records and each record has to be edited and deleted.

The generated records look like this

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="edit" id="edit-id-300" alt="edit-type-1">Record1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="delete" id="delete-id-300" alt="delete-type-1">Record1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="edit" id="edit-id-301" alt="edit-type-1">Record2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="delete" id="delete-id-301" alt="delete-type-1">Record2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="edit" id="edit-id-302" alt="edit-type-2">Record3</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="delete" id="delete-id-302" alt="delete-type-2">Record3</a>
```

and my jquery code handle them would be

```
$(".edit").click(function() {
    var currentElementId = $(this).attr("id").replace("edit-id-","");
    $("#ajaxdiv").load("ajaxpage.php","editid="+currentElementId);
});
```

is this type of stuff ok? i mean is there any other way to do stuff like this especially when this gets more complicated like have to add 3 more identifiers to id and then exploding them and finding out each of the identifiers separately. Any guidelines here to follow.?

Comment: Why use a link with a broken href, why not use a button, image, li or other more appropriate element? Anyway, you are likely better to use a single listener on a parent element, then use the bubbling event to get a reference to the appropriate element and use its class to determine what to do and its id to see what to do it too. Aka event delegation.

Comment: @RobG, so you're advocating a large switch statement in this day and age? After recommending to stay away from `<a>` for links? Seriously? Wow and someone upvoted him.

Comment: @Blindy - it does make sense to not abuse a link just for the hand cursor - the link is pointing to something that will degrade into an ugly error message. A button or span with a hand cursor makes more sense to me and I expect @RobG too. At least the link should be to a page that explains that JS is mandatory and the link should return false onclick too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply need to have something that can be cleaner, maybe you can consider bind the record into one 
meaningful div, and use .live() to bind the event handlers
i.e.,

```
<div data-rec-id = '300'>
    ...
    <span class='link del' data-act='del'>Delete</span>
    <span class='link edit' data-act='edit'>Edit</span>
</div>
<div data-rec-id = '301'>
    ...
    <span class='link del' data-act='del'>Delete</span>
    <span class='link edit' data-act='edit'>Edit</span>
</div>

$('.edit').live('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('[data-rec-id]').attr('data-rec-id');
    $("#ajaxdiv").load("ajaxpage.php","editid="+id);
});
```

or even generic:

```
$('.link').live('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('[data-rec-id]').attr('data-rec-id');
    var action = $(this).attr('data-act');
    $("#ajaxdiv").load("ajaxpage.php","id="+id+"&act="+action);
});
```

Please don't use something like:

```
<a href="javascript:;" ...
```

or I would suggest you use some robust framework. e.g., http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you've done it is acceptable. You're mostly concerned about manually doing string processing to fetch the element ID? That is a little messy but not too bad.

If you don't want to do it that way, you might consider attaching a separate event handler to each `a` element when you create them, and have that event handler know the ID as a closure variable. But that will consume more memory, so it will depend on how many of those links you have.

Answer (score -1):

I've found using using the web server to server up static web pages with the only dynamic content being json passed back and forth, is the best overall approach.  We post JSON, and get JSON back from the server.  This is used to design the page.  This makes the web server become a data communication rather than heavy lifting the page constructing.  This also add the ability for an API structure you can give out to ppl and they can write apps for it.  For example, the web site and the mobile application use the same API interface.

Comment: -1 Very good advice, but I don't see it having anything to do with this question, which is about how to use jQuery.

Comment: Well originally, it was also tagged with PHP.  I was giving interactive advise which would probably change the ajax calling.  I've also found $(document.querySelectorAll('.classname')) to be almost 4 times faster than $('.classname'), in browsers that support it.